# Disabling store views in Magento for improving performance

Tags: magento, magmi

I need to improve indexing times, specifically "Product Prices".

I would like to know if I need to actually delete a store view in order to improve indexing performance, or would it be enough to disable it. I'm talking about store views in different websites in a multi-site Magento installation.

How much does an extra store view affect performance with tens of thousands of products, each with different prices per store view (the other attributes are the same)?

Thank you.

Comment: Reindexing tens of thousands of products takes time.. so yes it'd improve performance, but by how much would be answered by you setting up a staging site to test that out. The better question might be why you need to improve indexing times.

Comment: I need to improve indexing times because I'm importing products quite often. My main question concerns disabling or deleting the views. Yes, I can setup a test scenario, but it would save me a lot of trouble, time and server "load/capacity" if someone helped me cut a corner on this. Isn't saving time and trouble the main reason why most of us are here? Disable ou delete? :) Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to say you were lazy -- but that you are literally the only one that can give a good answer on how much time will be cut out of your indexing process. There are many variables to consider that we don't know about.

Comment: Indexations are still a mistery to me. I've repeated the same indexing process without changing anything in the website, but still end up getting very different times (30 minutes and later on 1 hour...).

Answer (score 4):

Magento does not check if store view is disabled. If you will not index this data you must delete the store view, create your own indexer or rewrite magento's indexing behavior.